# Suppress blog footer in Jekyll/Kramdown

Tags: jekyll, footer, kramdown

I'm using Jekyll with Kramdown on Github. The title of my blog, which I put in `_config.yml`, appears in the header of the page but also twice in the footer. I would like to suppress the two appearances in the footer. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: It depends on the template you are using.

Comment: @marcanuy In `_layouts` I found only `default.html`, which includes the lines `{% include head.html %}`, `{% include header.html %}`, and `{% include footer.html %}`. However I don't see where to edit those.

Comment: That is inserting the code found in `_includes` folder, update the question with the code present in `/_includes/footer.html`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As said in comments, the code you need to edit is located in `/_includes/footer.html`.

There you would find the title of your blog printed twice, remove one and it should work.

> `include` tag tag allows you to include the content from another file stored in the _includes folder"

You can read more here: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/

---

Not having the includes directory means you are using **Jekyll themes**.

1. Look in _config.yml the line that starts with "theme: " , like for example "`theme: minima`" and note that name.
2. Now you need to copy that theme includes directory into your Jekyll site directory so you can edit it. Locate that theme with: `bundle show <theme name>` for example:

   ```
    bundle show minima
   ```

   It will return something like: `/var/lib/gems/minima`
3. Copy the `_includes` directory to your Jekyll dir.

   ```
    cp -r /var/lib/gems/minima/_includes .
   ```
4. Open `./_includes/footer.html` and locate the repeating title.

Comment: For some reason I only see the folders `_layouts` and `_posts`. Does this mean I set up something incorrectly?

Comment: @user7843034 I've updated the answer, hope that helps!

Answer (score 4):

This is a layout issue, not a configuration one.

Please see in _layouts or _includes, depending on your template, where the value is outputted and fix it there.

In case you are not seeing a _layouts or _includes folder, chances are you are using a [Jekyll theme](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/themes/). With Jekyll Themes you are loading these files from a Gem file. However, you can customise them by copy/pasting the desired files to your local folder and modify it there. It is possible you override _layouts, but not the _includes.

In this case, you need to do the following:

1. Check in _config what theme you are using. Let's say it's "minima", the default.
2. Do: `bundle show minima` to get the location of the theme. Open the directory, in example for OSX/macOS it would be: `open $(bundle show minima)` in Terminal.
3. Copy/Paste the Gems `_includes/footer.html` to a local folder. In example, create a folder called `_includes` in your working directory and copy the file there. Make sure the folder names match.
4. Do that with all files you want to override. And finally customise them.

The above linked Theme Docs do explain what I described above more in detail.

Comment: In `_layouts` I found only `default.html`, which includes the lines `{% include head.html %}`, `{% include header.html %}`, and `{% include footer.html %}`. However I don't see where to edit those.

Comment: All includes should be in the _includes folder.

Comment: For some reason I only see the folders `_layouts` and `_posts`. Does this mean I set up something incorrectly?

Comment: Not necessarily. Do you have a Jekyll theme installed? In this case it is possible your site overrides the _layout, but not the include. If this is the case, you need to copy/paste the themes include to a folder you need to create and override it there. I update my answer